# Compiling a project through command line

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I have a android project which I build through android studio and it worked fine. Then I took a new system and I am trying to build it through command line with this command :

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

which is giving me error this:

```
could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1
```

How to resolve this.

Comment: try changing support library

Comment: How do I change that, could you please tell me @ShivamOberoi

Comment: have you done this way compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1.'

Comment: Make sure that the Google maven repo is configured correctly as described here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html#add-library

Comment: Yes trying add that i send you in your build.gradle

Comment: what is your SDK version? yea, please add your `build.gradle`